# Selenium C# - It is selecting a cell from wrong table

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath, webdriver

I'm new using Selenium, and I'm trying to select a value from a table. I do that 3 times (for 3 different tables) but if this value is repeated, Selenium selects the value from the first table.

For example:

In **table 1**, there's a value "X123", the code select it, no problem.
In **table 2**, there's also a value "X123". When Selenium tries to select the value from the second table, it ends up selecting the value from the first table.

It's really hard to map the elements for these tables, they are all built in the same structure, so I chose XPath Selector for that, as following:

```
    [FindsBy(How = How.XPath, Using = "//div[@class='k-widget k-window' and not(contains(@style, 'display: none'))]//child::div[@class='col-md-4 col-md-offset-0'][1]//child::table[@data-role='selectable']")]
    private IWebElement Table1 { get; set; }

    [FindsBy(How = How.XPath, Using = "//div[@class='k-widget k-window' and not(contains(@style, 'display: none'))]//child::div[@class='col-md-4 col-md-offset-0'][2]//child::table[@data-role='selectable']")]
    private IWebElement Table2 { get; set; }

    [FindsBy(How = How.XPath, Using = "//div[@class='k-widget k-window' and not(contains(@style, 'display: none'))]//child::div[@class='col-md-4 col-md-offset-0'][3]//child::table[@data-role='selectable']")]
    private IWebElement Table3{ get; set; }
```

The function used to select the cell is:

```
    public static void SelectMultipleGridCell(this IWebElement table, string value)
    {
        IList<IWebElement> tableRow = table.FindElements(By.XPath("//tr//td[text()='" + value + "']"));
        new WebDriverWait(GeneralProperties.Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5))
            .Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.XPath("//tr//td[text()='" + value + "']")));
        foreach (IWebElement row in tableRow)
        {
            if (row.IsVisible())
            {
                new Actions(GeneralProperties.Driver).KeyDown(Keys.Control).Click(row).KeyUp(Keys.Control).Build().Perform();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

For all other conditions using this function, it works fine (selecting multiple cells in the table, just one, etc.). It only doesn't work as expected if the value is repeated. Is my code wrong or there's some limitation with Selenium about it?

Any help woul be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a dot in front of your XPath to search for a descendant. Otherwise it will search from the root.

```
public static void SelectMultipleGridCell(this IWebElement table, string value)
{
    IList<IWebElement> tableRow = table.FindElements(By.XPath(".//tr//td[text()='" + value + "']"));

    foreach (IWebElement row in tableRow)
    {
        if (row.IsVisible())
        {
            new Actions(GeneralProperties.Driver).KeyDown(Keys.Control).Click(row).KeyUp(Keys.Control).Build().Perform();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! I dit a test and didn't work.. It's still selecting the value from first table.

Comment: This error is not related to the issue you are describing and I doubt that it's related to the dot in front of the XPath.

Comment: Sorry, I expressed myself wrong (even changed my comment when noticed). The behavior is still wrong. It should select the value from the second table, just as the element indicates, but it is selecting from the first table

Comment: Now it's working perfectly! I put the dot in the XPaths in the function **SelectMultipleGridCell** instead of [FindsBy(..)] and now it's totally ok. Thank you so much!